# How can I calculate ePCP and/or Brier scores for a mixed-effects logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, brier-score

I am trying to calculate ePCP and Brier scores in R for a mixed-effect binary logistic regression. It cannot seem to find any packages that work for mixed models. I have tried the packages OOmisc and ModelGood, and spent much time searching the web with no success.

I am using the lme4 package to fit the regression.

I would be very grateful for any tips.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about searching for an R package.

Comment: Sorry if it is off topic. I was wondering if anyone knows a way, in R or otherwise, to calculate these./

Comment: Try reformulating your question as about the relevant statistical issues & we can re-open it. If you only want to know about what code / package, you could try the r-help listserv, which would be a better option for you anyway. There is also a specialized listserv for mixed models you could try.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the predict function, as you would with a regular glm model, there is nothing special about calculating a brier score from a mixed model.